# Dependency Injection on SignalR in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr, asp.net-core-mvc

**Note:**

For brevity, I reduced my codes and made it simple.

**Codes/Setup:**

I have a class:

```
class MyService
{
    public Guid InstanceID = Guid.NewGuid;
```

I added `MyService` in my services as scoped:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddScoped<MyService, MyService>();
```

Then in my view, I inject the service:

```
@inject MyService _myService

@_myService.InstanceID //display
```

The code above displays different result each request, as expected from a scoped service.

However, when injecting the service in SignalR Hub, I always get the same output.

```
MyHub(MyService myService)
{
    _myService = myService; 
}

public void Test()
{
     Clients.Caller.Log(_myService.InstanceID); //Log is a custom function in JS
```

Although the Hub itself is instantiated every call to `Test()`, the instance of `MyService` being injected to it is always the same.

**My Requirement:**

I want a new instance of `MyService` to be injected in Hub the same way in Controller/View every request.

**Question:**

Is this the default behavior of SignalR? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Packages Used:**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets" Version="0.2.0-*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server" Version="0.2.0-rtm-22752" />
```

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server is deprecated and won't ship.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change `AddScoped` to `Transient`. Because the first one is created once per request and second is created each time it is requested.

You could check more details in [Service Lifetimes and Registration Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options) section.

Also, you could check [How to handle connection lifetime events in the Hub class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#connectionlifetime) for the understanding difference with Controller/View request.

Comment: this `smells` like a good answer.  its a bit light on detail, but probably has to be a full blog post to explain it all.